# Converting a string of letters into numbers

Tags: java

So I'm new to computer science and one of the things we've been asked to do is to attempt to create a program that firstly converts a word inputted by the user into a string of numbers, with a=1, b=2, z=26 etc. along with some other things which I wont go into now as they're extension. Admittedly she says she doesn't mind if we complete it as it was our first proper java lesson today.

So in light of that, can anyone give me any *tips* on how to do this? I don't want a complete piece of code to do exactly that as I need to learn and so a guiding hand instead would be greatly appreciated. What I have written so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class main
{
 /**
 * Constructor for objects of class main
 */
public static void main(String [ ] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = "";
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter a word: ");
    word = keyboard.nextLine();
    for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
    {

    }
}
```

There's pretty much nothing there I know, but as mentioned we haven't exactly learnt anything yet so that's all I've managed to get in so far, and to be honest there's probably something wrong there already.

My assumption is there's a way for me to convert each letter to it's number (maybe the numbers are already assigned to letters in Java?) in a for loop. My only other idea is to convert it to an array, have another array with the numbers in and find a way to output the relevant counterpart. But I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Anthony

Comment: "Maybe the numbers are already assigned to letters in Java?" Yes. It's simple but has some deep details. Characters are members of a character set, which associates a character with a number, called a codepoint. The codepoint has to be stored in bytes by transforming the number somehow. Unicode has several encodings in use. Java strings use UTF-16. Files and streams often use UTF-8. Each computer has a "default" character set and encoding. That's what your [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.InputStream-) reads, returning a UTF-16 string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract two char variables. This gives the difference between their ASCII values.

```
for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
{
    char c = word.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(c - 'a' +1);
}
```

Comment: In Java (.NET, JavaScript, …) a string is a sequence of UTF-16 code units, one or two of which encode a Unicode codepoint (character). For this to work, the data has to contain only lowercase basic latin letters, and you have to know that each of those codepoints are encoded in UTF-16 as one code unit (so subtraction makes sense) and that they are consecutively numbered (so the result is useful). So, yes, `c - 'a'`, being a difference in UTF-16 code units, being, in this case, a difference in Unicode codepoints, gives the "distance from 'a'."

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you've read a `String` and need a `int[]` array where every number corresponds to letter in from `a = 1` to `z = 26`:

```
public int[] toNumbers(String s) {
    if (s == null)
        return null;
    int[] r = new int[s.length()];
    int i = 0;
    for (char c : s.toLowerCase().toCharArray())
       r[i++] = c - 'a' + 1;
    return r;
}
```

To print result, just use `Arrays.toString()`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use parseInt for int variable & parseDouble for double variable for e.g.
`String num1 = "123";  /* <-- it's a string no a number */
     String num2 = "2.3";
     int x = Integer.parseInt(num1); /* String is converted to int */
     int y = Double.parseDouble(num2); /* String is converted to double */`
.